# Calculating drainage density

Tags: qgis, hydrology

How can I calculate drainage density in QGIS if I have length for stream and grid line 1 km2? I need to calculate density per km2.

Comment: Hi, this forum, in contrast with many similar ones, does not intend to produce howtos but help you when you face a specific problem. So, it requires you to provide information about what have you tried and what went wrong, which tools you are using and anything that can help us to assess your problem

Comment: Have you looked at the GRASS addon [r.stream.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/addons/r.stream.stats.html)? I do not know how to access it from qgis, but having GRASS available in the `Proecessing toolbox`, there should be a way to do so